# JSP custom tag attribute type integer

Tags: java, jsp, attributes, custom-tags

I want to create a custom tag library but in the handler class I would like to have integer attributes.

In the tld file I have the following code:

```
<tag>
        <name>circle</name>
        <tag-class>draw.Circle</tag-class>
        <body-content>jsp</body-content>
        <attribute>
            <name>x</name>
            <required>true</required>
        </attribute>
</tag>
```

there are also other integer attributes, but this example is relevant for the others.

The handler class, for the moment looks this way:

```
public class Circle extends TagSupport{
    private Integer x;

    public Integer getX() {
        return x;
    }
    public void setX(String x) {
        this.x = Integer.parseInt(x);
        System.out.println("Set x");
    }
}
```

I haven't specified the attribute type in the tld file, and default it should be String. Though I get an error like this:

```
Unable to find setter method for attribute: x
```

I have also tried modifying the attribute type to: `<type>java.lang.Integer</type>` and the setter method to:

```
public void setX(int x) {
    }
```

And I get the same error.

How should I define the attribute in the tld file and the setter in the handler class so that I don't get the setter error?

Comment: What happens if you change the getter return type to String?

Comment: Do all the types match up (getter return, setter param, type in TLD)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSP custom tags use the [JavaBeans](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-138795.html) technology, which has standard conventions (here's [a small JavaBeans tutorial](http://java.blogs.webucator.com/2010/04/17/javabeans-tutorial/) that captures the main aspects).

A "bean property" (see [`PropertyDescriptor`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyDescriptor.html)) consists of a [getter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyDescriptor.html#getReadMethod%28%29) and / or a [setter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyDescriptor.html#getWriteMethod%28%29) method of the same type (return type of the getter must match single param type of the setter), otherwise they are not mapped to the same bean property (I'm guessing the first method in the class "wins"). So your Integer getter / String setter approach can't work, as the String setter will not be detected as belonging to the Integer property).

Set the parameter type of the setter method to `Integer` and it will work, the conversion will be applied automatically, JavaBeans has built-in support for value conversion through the [`PropertyEditor`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyEditor.html) interface (implementations for at least all primitive value types exist, and through auto-unboxing, `Integer` can be considered primitive).

Comment: I'll try this. And should this also work for color type java.awt.Color?

Comment: @AlinaDanila I don't know if a PropertyEditor exists for Color, but you can check. Otherwise use String or Integer getters and setters and do the conversions inside them.

Comment: I've found [`ColorEditor`](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/sun/beans/editors/ColorEditor.java.html), but that's tightly integrated with Swing, unfortunately